# Complex Poynting vector and energy loss

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, power, poynting-vector

Consider continuum medium (no boundaries) and the electromagnetic wave Poynting vector
$$ \mathbf{S} = \mathbf{E}\times \mathbf{H}^*$$
with $^*$ the complex conjugate. When there is a phase difference between $E$ and $H$, then the Poynting vector becomes a complex value. The real part of the Poynting vector corresponds to the net energy flow through a unit surface (active power), whereas the complex part corresponds to the oscillating power flow through a unit surface (reactive power).

Based on this, I do not understand the following:

- So, when there is a phase difference between $E$ and $H$, the complex part of the Poynting vector corresponds to standing, evanescent waves? How do I have to interpret a propagating electromagnetic wave that generates stationary oscillating power in an infinite medium? How can a propagating wave also generate an evanescent field in this infinite medium?
- If there is a phase difference between $E$ and $H$, this means that the permittivity is complex, which also means that there is energy loss of the wave. Is this energy loss also captured by the Poynting vector? Or is the imaginary part of the Poynting vector the energy loss? Or can there be a phase difference between $E$ and $H$ without energy loss?

Summary of questions:

- If there is a phase difference between $E$ and $H$, the Poynting vector is complex and there is a loss in the medium. Does this mean that a lossy wave always has a reactive field associated with it?
- Does the Poynting vector take into account/correlate with energy losses? If yes, how?
- Does a phase difference between $E$ and $H$ always correspond to energy losses (via complex permittivity) or can it also correspond to lossless standing/evanescent waves?
- Can a lossless propagating wave have an imaginary part of the Poynting vector?